# In React Component How to Bind Object Value?

Tags: reactjs

I am a newbie in React Js. I have to develop a small application using React Js.I fetch the data from api call and bind the value into component.Try some code but getting error.

> object with keys {HeaderModel}). If you meant to render a collection
>   of children, use an array instead.

```
{
  "HeaderModel":
        {
        "DataModel": null,
        "HeaderLogo": "test.jpg",
         "HeaderLink1": AboutUS,
        "HeaderLink2": ContactUS,
        "HeaderLink3": Register,
        "LoginButtonText": "LOGIN",
        "LoginButtonTextLink": "http://sample.com",
        "ContactLogo": "fa fa-question-circle"
      }   
}
```

Below code refer React JS file.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../Assests/css/main.css";
import data from "../Constants/SampleJson/TestJson.json";

class Header extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  state = {
    values: null,
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="main-header">
        <p>{this.state.values}</p> // Getting Error
        <div class="container">
          <div className="header-sticky">
            <div class="logo-wrap">
              <a href="/" target="_self">
                {/* <img src={require({items.HeaderLogo})} /> */}
              </a>
              <h1>{this.state.values.HeaderModel.HeaderLogo}</h1> //// Getting Error while biniding
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("http://loalhost:55423/api/TestAPIController/GetPageData")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            values: result,
          });
          console.log(test);
        },
        // Note: it's important to handle errors here
        // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
        // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error,
          });
        }
      );
  }
}

export default Header;
```

API Response Like Below

```
{
    "HeaderModel":
        {
            "DataModel":null,
            "HeaderLogo":"sample.jpg",
            "HeaderLink1":"contactus",
            "HeaderLink2":"aboutus",
            "HeaderLink3":"register",
            "LoginButtonText":"LOGIN",
            "LoginButtonTextLink":"http://sample.com",
            "ContactLogo":"fa fa-question-circle"
       }
}
```

Comment: Can you add a console.log(result) in then block and add to the question?

Comment: @SuleymanSah i have update console.log(result) in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors you are getting are quite easy to solve.

The first one with the `<p>{this.state.values}</p>` is related to the fact that `this.state.values` is an object after you fetch the data. React doesn't support displaying objects, thus you get the proposition to try something else. In order to fix it, either remove this tag entirely or change it to `<p>{JSON.stringify(this.state.values)}</p>` so it's displayed as a nice string.

The second problem is that in `<h1>{this.state.values.HeaderModel.HeaderLogo}</h1>` `this.state.values` is null before the fetch is complete. In order to fix it, you should not render this `h1` tag before the state is changed. This can be fixed by showing it conditionally with the `&&` operator

Here is the modified code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../Assests/css/main.css";
import data from "../Constants/SampleJson/TestJson.json";

class Header extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  state = {
    values: null,
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="main-header">
        <p>{JSON.stringify(this.state.values)}</p> // Getting Error
        <div class="container">
          <div className="header-sticky">
            <div class="logo-wrap">
              <a href="/" target="_self">
                {/* <img src={require({items.HeaderLogo})} /> */}
              </a>
              {this.state.values && <h1>{this.state.values.HeaderModel.HeaderLogo}</h1>} 
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("http://loalhost:55423/api/TestAPIController/GetPageData")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            values: result,
          });
          console.log(test);
        },
        // Note: it's important to handle errors here
        // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
        // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error,
          });
        }
      );
  }
}

export default Header;
```

Comment: Thanks for your rply Adam. Your 1st point its okay the JSON obect dispplay in page. but i tried in 2nd point but its shows error like "TypeError: Cannot read property 'HeaderLogo' of undefined
" kindly assist.

Comment: Looks like for some reason the `HeaderModel` is not defined in the result from the API :/ I will look into that

Comment: i got value from API. the value display as a JSON format in the page. at the time of binding its shows error

Comment: I got answer , after get response . I need to parse the result .Now i am able to bind the value.

Answer (score 0):

There seems 2 issues here:

- Object is not valid react child and so, you can't directly show `this.state.values` on screen. You can convert it to array and then render on screen or render individual elements (see next points).
- `this.state.values.HeaderModel.HeaderLogo` will give you error. For first render (before API fetches you the data), `this.state.values` is null so this will also fail. You can use `&&` operator to fix it. `this.state.values && this.state.values.HeaderModel.HeaderLogo` should fix it for you.

Here is a one of many possible solution that will work:

```
render() {
    const headerModel = this.state.values && this.state.values.HeaderModel || {}
    return (
      <div className="main-header">
        {Object.values(headerModel).map(value => <p>value</p>)} // fix 1
        <div class="container">
          <div className="header-sticky">
            <div class="logo-wrap">
              <a href="/" target="_self">
                {/* <img src={require({items.HeaderLogo})} /> */}
              </a>
              <h1>{headerModel.HeaderLogo}</h1> //// Getting Error while biniding
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Hope it helps. Revert for any doubts.

Comment: but its shows error like "TypeError: Cannot read property 'HeaderLogo' of undefined " kindly assist

Comment: Add a console.log(headerModel, this.state.values) in render to see if the values are properly alloted after API call has happened

Comment: I got answer , after get response . I need to parse the result .Now i am able to bind the value.